# NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null I/flutter ( 8622): Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => Result)

Tags: flutter, dart

I/flutter ( 8622): NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 8622): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 8622): Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => Result)

hello i got an error look like that.
i dont know what to do. i've tried so many solution but it didn't work
sorry for my enlish im still learing flutter

here's my code
sorry for my long code

this ui screen

```
class JualSampah extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? token;
  const JualSampah({Key? key, this.token}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _JualSampahState createState() => _JualSampahState();
}

int _n = 01;

class Img {
  String nama, images;
  Img({required this.nama, required this.images});
}

class _JualSampahState extends State<JualSampah> {
  final con = HomeController();

  String? token;
  List qtyList = [];
  List totalHarga = [];
  List postDetail = [];
  List hargaSetor = [];
  List namaSampah = [];
  List<Result> _listSampah = <Result>[];
  List<Result> _listSearch = <Result>[];

  var _controller = TextEditingController();
  Timer? debounce;
  String search = '';

  RefreshController _refreshController =
      RefreshController(initialRefresh: false);

  void _onRefresh() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
    _listSampah.clear();

    _refreshController.refreshCompleted();
  }

  void _onLoading() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
    _listSampah.clear();

    _refreshController.loadComplete();
  }

  Color setor = Colors.grey;

  @override
  void initState() {
    getToken().then((value) {
      con.getSampahId(value);
      setState(() {
        token = value;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
    //! menggunakan qtyList
    con.resSampah.listen((value) {
      for (var i = 0; i < value.result!.length; i++) {
        qtyList.add(0);
        postDetail.add(0);
        namaSampah.add(0);
        hargaSetor.add(0);
        totalHarga.add(0);
      }

      if (mounted)
        setState(() {
          if (_listSampah.isNotEmpty) {
            if (mounted)
              setState(() {
                _listSampah.clear();
              });
          } else {
            _listSampah.addAll(value.result!);
            _listSearch = _listSampah;
          }
        });
    });
  }

  // @override
  // void dispose() {
  //   super.dispose();
  //   _listSampah.clear();
  //   _listSearch.clear();
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Stack(children: [
      Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.75,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, left: 10),
          child: ListView(children: [
            Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                height: 70,
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.arrow_back_ios_new_rounded,
                        size: 25,
                        color: Color(0xff85d057),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 30,
                    ),
                    Text("Jual Sampah",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 20,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        )),
                  ],
                )),
            Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                height: 50,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                    color: Color(0xffF0FFEB)),
                child: TextField(
                  controller: _controller,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      prefixIcon: Icon(
                        Icons.search,
                        color: Color(0xff85d057),
                      ),
                      hintText: "Search Sampah",
                      hintStyle:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 15, color: Colors.grey[400])),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    _listSampah.where((element) {
                      var sampah = element.nama!.toLowerCase();
                      return sampah.contains(value);
                    }).toList();
                  },
                )),
            SizedBox(height: 15),
            Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                child: _listSearch.isEmpty
                    ? Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        // padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              child: ListView.builder(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                itemBuilder: (context, _) => Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12.0),
                                  child: Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Container(
                                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 12),
                                        height: 110,
                                        width: 110,
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(8),
                                            color: Colors.white),
                                      ),
                                      Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment:
                                            CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Container(
                                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                bottom: 8, top: 8, left: 8),
                                            height: 10,
                                            width: 150,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          ),
                                          Container(
                                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                                bottom: 8, left: 8),
                                            height: 10,
                                            width: 200,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          ),
                                          Container(
                                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8),
                                            height: 10,
                                            width: 80,
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: 3,
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                itemCount: 6,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ))
                    : SmartRefresher(
                        enablePullDown: true,
                        enablePullUp: false,
                        header: WaterDropMaterialHeader(),
                        controller: _refreshController,
                        onRefresh: _onRefresh,
                        onLoading: _onLoading,
                        child: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 70),
                          height: 400,
                          child: _listSearch.isEmpty
                              ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                              : ListView.builder(
                                  physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  itemCount: _listSearch.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    if (qtyList[index] != 0) {
                                      postDetail[index] = {
                                        "id_sampah": _listSampah[index].id,
                                        "Jumlah": qtyList[index],
                                        "harga": _listSampah[index].hargaSetor
                                      };
                                      namaSampah[index] =
                                          _listSampah[index].nama;
                                      hargaSetor[index] =
                                          _listSampah[index].hargaSetor;
                                    } else {
                                      postDetail[index] = 0;
                                      namaSampah[index] = 0;
                                      hargaSetor[index] = 0;
                                    }
                                    Result sampah = _listSampah[index];
                                    return Container();
                                                                },
                                                                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                                                    backgroundColor:
                                                                        Color(
                                                                            0xffE0E0E0),
                                                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                                        borderRadius:
                                                                            BorderRadius.circular(10))),
                                                              ),
                                                            )
                                                          : Container(
                                                              margin: EdgeInsets
                                                                  .all(10),
                                                              width: 35,
                                                              height: 35,
                                                              child: TextButton(
                                                                onPressed:
                                                                    () {},
                                                                child: Icon(
                                                                  Icons.remove,
                                                                  size: 20,
                                                                  color: Color(
                                                                      0xff909090),
                                                                ),
                                                                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                                                    backgroundColor:
                                                                        Color(
                                                                            0xffE0E0E0),
                                                                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                                        borderRadius:
                                                                            BorderRadius.circular(10))),
                                                              ),
                                                            ),
                                                      Text(qtyList[index]
                                                          .toString()),
                                                      Container(
                                                          margin:
                                                              EdgeInsets.all(
                                                                  10),
                                                          width: 35,
                                                          height: 35,
                                                          child: TextButton(
                                                            child: Align(
                                                                alignment:
                                                                    Alignment
                                                                        .center,
                                                                child: Icon(
                                                                  Icons.add,
                                                                  size: 20,
                                                                  color: Color(
                                                                      0xff909090),
                                                                )),
                                                            onPressed: () {
                                                              setState(() {
                                                                qtyList[index] =
                                                                    qtyList[index] +
                                                                        1;
                                                                totalHarga[
                                                                    index] = _listSampah[
                                                                            index]
                                                                        .hargaSetor! *
                                                                    qtyList[
                                                                        index];
                                                                if (totalHarga.reduce(
                                                                        (a, b) =>
                                                                            a +
                                                                            b) ==
                                                                    0) {
                                                                  setor = Colors
                                                                      .grey;
                                                                } else {
                                                                  setor = Colors
                                                                      .green;
                                                                }
                                                              });
                                                            },
                                                            style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                                                                backgroundColor:
                                                                    Color(
                                                                        0xffE0E0E0),
                                                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                                    borderRadius:
                                                                        BorderRadius.circular(
                                                                            10))),
                                                          )),
                                                      Text(
                                                        "Rp : " +
                                                            sampah.hargaSetor!
                                                                .toString(),
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                            fontWeight:
                                                                FontWeight
                                                                    .bold),
                                                      )
                                                    ],
                                                  ),
                                                )
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  }),
                        ),
                      )),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
      DraggableScrollableSheet(),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: 100,
            color: Colors.white,
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _listSampah.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Text("Total"),
                            Text(
                              "Rp. ${totalHarga.reduce((a, b) => a + b)}",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        height: 50,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              primary: Color(0xff85d057),
                              onPrimary: Colors.white, // foreground
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => Sukses()));
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              'Jual Sampah',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 19,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontFamily: "Roboto"),
                            )),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                })),
      ),
    ])));
  }
 
}
```

and this my model for my screen

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final getSampah = getSampahFromMap(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

class GetSampah {
  GetSampah({
    this.hasil,
    this.result,
  });

  bool? hasil;
  List<Result>? result;

  factory GetSampah.fromJson(String str) => GetSampah.fromMap(json.decode(str));

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory GetSampah.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => GetSampah(
        hasil: json["hasil"],
        result: List<Result>.from(json["result"].map((x) => Result.fromMap(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "hasil": hasil,
        "result": List<dynamic>.from(result!.map((x) => x.toMap())),
      };
}

class Result {
  Result({
    this.id,
    this.nama,
    this.kode,
    this.jenis,
    this.jumlah,
    this.hargaSetor,
    this.hargaJual,
    this.foto,
    this.createdAt,
    this.v,
  });

  String? id;
  String? nama;
  String? kode;
  String? jenis;
  String? jumlah;
  int? hargaSetor;
  int? hargaJual;
  String? foto;
  DateTime? createdAt;
  int? v;

  factory Result.fromJson(String str) => Result.fromMap(json.decode(str));

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Result.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Result(
        id: json["_id"],
        nama: json["Nama"],
        kode: json["Kode"],
        jenis: json["Jenis"],
        jumlah: json["Jumlah"],
        hargaSetor: json["HargaSetor"],
        hargaJual: json["HargaJual"],
        foto: json["Foto"],
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["CreatedAt"]),
        v: json["__v"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "_id": id,
        "Nama": nama,
        "Kode": kode,
        "Jenis": jenis,
        "Jumlah": jumlah,
        "HargaSetor": hargaSetor,
        "HargaJual": hargaJual,
        "Foto": foto,
        "CreatedAt": createdAt!.toIso8601String(),
        "__v": v,
      };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry the answer is because the API has changed so the JSON code is diffrent thankss before

Answer (score 1):

Your json["result"] is null. If there is a Result id is not null. Check the logique to add "as String" or"as String?" in fromMap.

```
class Result {
  Result({
    required this.id,
    this.nama,
    this.kode,
    this.jenis,
    this.jumlah,
    this.hargaSetor,
    this.hargaJual,
    this.foto,
    this.createdAt,
    this.v,
  });

  String id;
  String? nama;
  String? kode;
  String? jenis;
  String? jumlah;
  int? hargaSetor;
  int? hargaJual;
  String? foto;
  DateTime? createdAt;
  int? v;

  factory Result.fromJson(String str) => Result.fromMap(json.decode(str));

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Result.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Result(
      id: map['id'] as String,
      nama: map['nama'] as String?,
      kode: map['kode'] as String?,
      jenis: map['jenis'] as String?,
      jumlah: map['jumlah'] as String?,
      hargaSetor: map['hargaSetor'] as int?,
      hargaJual: map['hargaJual'] as int?,
      foto: map['foto'] as String?,
      createdAt: map['createdAt'] as DateTime?,
      v: map['v'] as int?,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'nama': nama,
      'kode': kode,
      'jenis': jenis,
      'jumlah': jumlah,
      'hargaSetor': hargaSetor,
      'hargaJual': hargaJual,
      'foto': foto,
      'createdAt': createdAt,
      'v': v,
    };
  }
}
```

And in the GetSampah() at least the result should be empty.

```
class GetSampah {
  GetSampah({
    required this.hasil,
    required this.result,
  });

  bool hasil;
  List<Result> result;

  factory GetSampah.fromJson(String str) => GetSampah.fromMap(json.decode(str));

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory GetSampah.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => GetSampah(
    hasil: json["hasil"],
    result: List<Result>.from(json["result"].map((x) => Result.fromMap(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "hasil": hasil,
    "result": List<dynamic>.from(result.map((x) => x.toMap())),
  };
}
```

Comment: its still give an error but i tried adding `result: json["result"] != null? List<Result>.from(json["result"].map((x) => Result.fromMap(x))) : <Result>[],` the error is gone but the data won't show up in ui screen